# Papaparse - console log a row

Tags: javascript, fs, papaparse

Trying to `console.log()` a row of data read in with papaparse but I'm just getting an array of [object Object].  How do I `console.log` the row of unwrapped values?

```
var fs = require('fs');
eval(fs.read('papaparse.min.js'));

var config = {
    delimiter: "",  // auto-detect
    newline: "",    // auto-detect
    header: true,
    dynamicTyping: false,
    preview: 0,
    encoding: "utf-8",
    worker: false,
    comments: false,
    step: undefined,
    complete: undefined,
    error: undefined,
    download: false,
    skipEmptyLines: true,
    chunk: undefined,
    fastMode: undefined
};

var file = Papa.parse(fs.read('some_file.csv'), config);

for (var row in file.data) {
    // this prints [object Object],[object Object], etc
    console.log(file.data);

    // How do I get
    // value, value, value, value, etc

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Papa Parse result docs :

> data is an array of rows. If header is false, rows are arrays; otherwise they are objects of data keyed by the field name.

Also you are trying to log the whole array in each iteration. It is best not to use `for in` for arrays

Try

```
file.data.forEach(function(row){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
});
```

Comment: I am using headers.  Is it possible to unwrap the objects of data without keying them?

Comment: Can iterate the object. Not sure what you are trying to do with results. Also you can use first row for column info and just use flat arrays for all rows

Comment: I'm trying to write the row exactly how I read it into a new file.

Comment: As a json file? If so does it matter if it's objects or not?

Comment: As a .csv file.  If it's objects my .csv literally reads "[object Object]" as a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106500/discussion-between-progirlxoxo-and-charlietfl).